# Unit testing redis.asyncio Redis client

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

After migrating from sync redis.Redis to redis.asyncio Redis with BlockingConnectionPool my unit tests for redis repositories method stopped working. I tested my redis methods manually and each works.

Mocked redis client:

```
import pytest_asyncio
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
from redis.asyncio import Redis

@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def mock_redis_client():
    yield AsyncMock(spec=Redis)
```

Failing test:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_user_success(
    mock_redis_client,
    mock_create_user_model_object):
    user_redis_repository = UserRedisRepository(mock_redis_client)
    mock_redis_client.set.return_value = True
    is_created = await user_redis_repository.create_user(str(uuid4()), mock_create_user_model_object)
    assert isinstance(is_created, bool)
```

Error:

```
___________________________ test_create_user_success ___________________________

mock_redis_client = <AsyncMock spec='Redis' id='281472698902800'>
mock_create_user_model_object = CreateUserModel(email='email@example.com', password='passw0rd!', salt='123456789podwajkdjadsakdjkanw')

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_create_user_success(
        mock_redis_client,
        mock_create_user_model_object):
        mock_redis_client = AsyncMock(spec=Redis)
        user_redis_repository = UserRedisRepository(mock_redis_client)
        mock_redis_client.set.return_value = True
>       is_created = await user_redis_repository.create_user(str(uuid4()), mock_create_user_model_object)

app/tests/test_user_redis_repository.py:24: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <app.database.redis.repositories.user_repository.UserRedisRepository object at 0xffff78356790>
key_id = '15421d87-1c1b-49c1-8006-6b4b8adbe52d'
new_user = CreateUserModel(email='email@example.com', password='passw0rd!', salt='123456789podwajkdjadsakdjkanw')

    async def create_user(self, key_id: str, new_user: CreateUserModel) -> bool:
        try:
            expiry_time = datetime.timedelta(days=14)
>           is_user_created: bool = await self.redis_client.set(
                name=f"user:{key_id}:{str(new_user.email)}",
                ex=expiry_time,
                value=new_user.model_dump_json()
            )
E           TypeError: object bool can't be used in 'await' expression

app/database/redis/repositories/user_repository.py:30: TypeError
```

Method that is being tested:

```
class UserRedisRepository(BaseRedisRepository, UserRedisRepositoryABC):

    async def create_user(self, key_id: str, new_user: CreateUserModel) -> bool:
        try:
            expiry_time = datetime.timedelta(days=14)
            is_user_created: bool = await self.redis_client.set(
                name=f"user:{key_id}:{str(new_user.email)}",
                ex=expiry_time,
                value=new_user.model_dump_json()
            )
            if is_user_created == False:
                raise RedisSetError("Cannot create new user in database.")
            return is_user_created
        except (RedisError, ResponseError, ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:
            logger.error(f"UserRedisRepository.create_user() Error: {e}")
            raise RedisDatabaseError("Error related to the database occurred.")
```

I am getting the same error for all my tests for every type that assign to return_value/side_effect:

```
TypeError: object bool can't be used in 'await' expression
TypeError: object list can't be used in 'await' expression
TypeError: object bytes can't be used in 'await' expression
```

When I removed `spec=Redis` from mocked redis client - `yield AsyncMock(spec=Redis) -> yield AsyncMock()`,
my unit tests started working, so there is definitely problem with this client.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us your `mock_redis_client` fixture.

Comment: @larsks first part of code in the post.